# Dynamic variable in select statement

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to write a select statement that uses several keywords to search by. For example

```
SELECT id FROM my_mod mm WHERE (mm.name LIKE '%joe%' OR mm.name LIKE '%jim%');
```

What I would like to do is in the return data have a extra column that counts the number of times that row matches one of the like statements.

So for the one above if there is a name `jimjoe` it would have a count of 2 or if the name is `jim` it would have a count of 1. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I should also mention that I can't use temp tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select t.id,count(*) FROM
((select id from my_mod where name like '%jim%')
union all
(select id from my_mod where name like '%joe%')) t group by t.
```

[I check here how it works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a654d7/3)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN mm.name LIKE '%joe%' 
              AND mm.name LIKE '%jim%' THEN 2 
         ELSE 1 
       end AS cnt 
FROM   my_mod mm 
WHERE  mm.name LIKE '%joe%' 
        OR mm.name LIKE '%jim%'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response but what I want to do is return each row that matches the like statements plus an extra column that has a count of how many of the like statements are matched for that specific row.

Comment: HI, this returns each column but the count is for the total number of matches, what I require is if the rows name was "joe" then it would have a count of 1 and if the next row was "jimjoe" it would have a count of 2.

Comment: @cs1h, try this sql script. This query is more efficient because the query scans the table only once.

Comment: @cs1h - not sure how small is your requirement is but, using `explain above query` I learnt that this is best choice to choose. +1 to OA

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  COUNT(IF(name LIKE '%joe%', 1, NULL)) joe_count,
  COUNT(IF(name LIKE '%jim%', 1, NULL)) jim_count
FROM
  my_mod
WHERE
  name LIKE '%joe%' OR name LIKE '%jim%'
```